# XPath. How to select all text nodes but only selected 'option' in 'select' element

Tags: javascript, xpath

I need to get all text nodes.

But when `select` element is on page (which contains some options elements). Just one `option` element is visible, other elements should be skipped.

HTML (just an axample):

```html
<body onload="console.log(aaa());">
    <p>
        <span>hello</span>
        <span>world</span>
        <select>
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
            <option selected>three</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</body>
```

and I use following javascript code to use my xpath:

```javascript
function aaa() {
    XPathResult.of = function(selector) {
        return document.evaluate(selector, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    };

    XPathResult.prototype.toArray = function() {
        var nodes = [];
        var node = null;
        while ( (node = this.iterateNext()) ) {
            nodes.push(node);
        }
        return nodes;
    };

    return XPathResult.of("//body//text() | descendant::option[@selected]")
        .toArray()
        .map(function(node) {
            if ( node.nodeName == 'OPTION' ) { return node.value; }
            if ( node.nodeName == '#text' ) { return node.data.trim(); }
            throw new Error("unknown node type: " + node);
        })
        .filter(function(text) { return text.length; })

}
```

result of this is:

["hello", "world", "one", "two", "three", "three"]

but should be

["hello", "world", "three"]

Please help finish with needed xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//body//text()` will return *every* text node in the document. `//body//text() | descendant::option[@selected]` will return an union of every text node in the document *and* every `<option selected>` descendant of the current element — which is still every single text node in the document.

If you want every single text node in the document *except* `<option>` elements without a `@selected` attribute, you could do something like this to filter out the elements you don't want:

```
//body//text()[not(parent::option[not(@selected)])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use XPath union (`|`) to combine result of XPath for getting all text nodes which is not located within `<option>` tag and is not an empty text node :

```
//body//text()[not(parent::option) and normalize-space(.)]
```

... with XPath for getting all text nodes within selected `<option>` nodes :

```
//body//text()[parent::option[@selected]]
```

Combined XPath :

```
//body//text()[parent::option[@selected]] | //body//text()[not(parent::option) and normalize-space(.)]
```

Given HTML input as in this question the output of above XPath would be `["hello", "world", "three"]`